# How can you select code nodes that were added through templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, dom, dom-events, addeventlistener

So I am using the template method to dynamically add HTML content in a page, and I want to change the value of an input through an event listener.

Here's a completely random snippet of code as an example *(it's nonsensical on purpose)*:

```js
favoriteElement +=  `<div class="favorite__page JS-favoritePage">
            <p id="JS-amountOfFavorites">Quantity of saved pages : ${amount}</p>
            <input type="number" class="favoritesQuantity" name="amountOfFavorites" min="1" max="100" value="${value}">
          </div>`
```

So let's say that I want to have access to the value of the input, I'll declare a variable and get it through their query selector :

```js
let inputFavoritesQuantity = document.querySelector('input [class="favoritesQuantity"]');
```

Now I'll add an event listener:

```js
inputFavoritesQuantity.addEventListener("input", function(e){
let valueOfInput = e.target.value;

//Other code
}
```

Though **the problem is that I do not have access to the input because it's added with a *template***, so it gives an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`

I could add everything by hand using the properties `createElement`,`setAttribute`,`appendChild`...

*But it would make the code VERY long and difficult to maintain! (without even considering the fact on my code project I'd have to add 5 nested elements which have 5 attributes each!)*

Is there *another efficient* method to have access to an element with templates?

Comment: Have you considered the DOMParser() to convert your template into a useable DOM object?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response! I never considered using the property `DOMParser()` because I didn't even know it existed! 

I looked at the MDN doc on the examples provided on the `DOMParser()` (that redirected me to the `DOMParser.parseFromString`) and the examples given were rather complicated to understand

Though, could you please just give me a simpler example as to how it works?
I'd be very grateful!

Comment: I've supplied my Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOMParser compiles strings into a document. You need to access the
documentElement in order to add to the existing dom. Here's an example of use

```js
let amount = 100
let value = 50
favoriteElement =  `<div class="favorite__page JS-favoritePage">
            <p id="JS-amountOfFavorites">Quantity of saved pages : ${amount}</p>
            <input type="number" name="amountOfFavorites" min="1" max="100" value="${value}" />
          </div>`

// This converts the string and gets the documentElement.
var node = new DOMParser().parseFromString(favoriteElement, "text/html").documentElement

//Now we are working with an actual element and not a string of text.
let inputFavoritesQuantity = node.querySelector('input [class="favoritesQuantity"]');

node.addEventListener("input", function(e){
    let valueOfInput = e.target.value;
    console.log('value changed', valueOfInput);
})

var outputDiv = document.getElementById('content')
outputDiv.appendChild(node);
```

```html
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers Pellay!

Although I did a small mistake in my post, I forgor to add the `innerHTML` property on the variable `favoriteElement`. 

So I have one last question: 
Does the DOMParse work the same with or without the `innerHTML` property?

Comment: The DOMparser simply converts a string of text into a accessible DOM element. You can use the result of the parser (in this case the `node` variable) to select and manipulate elements as you see fit. `innerHTML` would not be be available on the `favoriteElement` because it's a string, but it is available on the `node`